# merge different shape 3-dimensionnal arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

So I have a probleme with a project i'm working on right now, I have 3 3D arrays, of shape (36,18,18), (18,36,18) and (18,18,36) and i need to merge them to have only one array of shape (36,36,36) does someone knows how to do that ?

Comment: Could you detail your problem? Because I do not see how to merge these three matrices, that is to say 18x18x36x3 elements, to create a new matrix of 36x36x36 elements knowing that the number of elements will be different.

Comment: Show us how you'd merge a (4,2) with a (2,4) (to make a (4,4)).  Full example please.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this same logic according to your input array type.

```
arr = [
    [36, 18, 18],
    [18, 36, 18],
    [18, 18, 36]
    ]
new_array = []
for outer_index, outer_list in enumerate(arr):
    for ind in range(len(outer_list)):
        if ind == outer_index:
            new_array.append(outer_list[ind])
print(new_array)
```

**Output:**

```
[36, 36, 36]
```